# Allow max 5 concurrent instances of a function at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-multithreading

I have the following function that is run in an independent thread. There can be up to 100 of these threads running concurrently.

```py
def do_stuff(item):
    """
    Assume up to ~100 of this function can run concurrently
    """

    # usually lasts 10-15 seconds
    # and no concurrency limit
    result_1 = unlimited_network_call()

    # usually lasts 20-25 seconds
    # only five of these can run concurrently
    result_2 = limited_network_call(result_1)

    # usually lasts 5-10 seconds
    # and no concurrency limit
    final_result = yet_another_network_call(result_2)

    return final_result
```

I can't think of the best approach to handle the following problem:

- the `do_stuff` function can run concurrently with no limit
- the `unlimited_network_call` is not concurrently limited as well
- however `limited_network_call` is and no more than 5 can run at a single time

I've tried using a queue with 5 workers each in its own thread, but the issue with that is I don't know how to communicate the result of the worker processing the item from the queue, back to the `do_stuff` function, while making the `do_stuff` function wait for this result.

Maybe there are other valid approaches that I wouldn't be thinking of.

Comment: I think semaphore can be useful in this scenario. You can give an initial value of 5 to the semaphore object and then surround  limited_network_call(result_1) between **acquire()** and **release()**  block. you can refer https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/semaphore-objects.html

Comment: @PranjalDoshi that's exactly what I was looking for